# How can I use an object outside of it's declared scope?

Tags: java, object

For example, if I have a class Student and an student object inside of it with the value of 5, also some getters and setters

```
public class Student {
    int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public static void run() {
        Student stud = new Student();
        stud.setAge(5);
    }
}
```

And I have another class called getStudent

```
public class GetStudent {
    int studAge = stud.getAge;
}
```

Now this, obviously, gives me an error. Is there any way to access the stud object and it's methods outside of it's class?

Comment: The same way you accessed `int age`--you pass it as a parameter or return it as a result.

Answer (score -2):

If you always want to access the Student object only through the `public static void run()` method, check out Singleton design pattern.